# Materialisation from the Immaterium

Tags: warhammer-40k

So I'm currently in a Dark Heresy campaign (pencil and paper ttrpg), and in our latest session, an event occurred that caused demons to come forth from the warp. However, after this was dealt with, their corpses (and a rock) was left behind.

Normally, this is absurd - Demons and materialisation from the Immaterium just doesn't happen. Half of the group are avid 40k fans, and understand the lore of the system, and therefore understand that this doesn't (or shouldn't) happen.

However the other half of the group are new to the lore, and so this passed by them somewhat. Is there any evidence of this in the lore that I can use to help explain this?

Comment: Did the demons inhabit the bodies of creatures in the material realm, as those are sometimes left behind

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. But the rock is the main part. It came from the same place the demons did.

Comment: Is the rock specifically from the immaterium? There are lots of instances were materials from the non warp have entered the warp and then come back again.

Comment: If it did, it came from somewhere, or some-when else